# Bootloop and inaccessible to fastboot /adb

Tags: adb, boot-loop, fastboot, twrp

So I wished to flash TWRP on my Gionee A1 (Nougat) and it couldn't mount my system partitions and reboots recovery repeatedly.
Reading somewhere cwm solves this, I did a grave mistake of flashing CWM of another device model onto mine (*as I couldn't find one for mine*)
After flashing, **the phone is in bootloop and I can't access recovery/fastboot**. Tried many methods but in vain. **Pls help**.

Answer (score 0):

Please attach your phone to adb installed pc using usb cable. Find terminal or command prompt. And run the following command 'adb reboot recovery'